# rewriting of Z3_ast during its traversing in C++

Tags: z3, abstract-syntax-tree

`to_expr` function leads to error. Could you advise what is wrong below?

```
context z3_cont;
expr x = z3_cont.int_const("x");
expr y = z3_cont.int_const("y");
expr ge = ((y==3) && (x==2));
ge = swap_tree( ge );
```

where `swap_tree` is a function that shall swap all operands of binary operations. It defined as follows.

```
expr swap_tree( expr e ) {
  Z3_ast ee[2];
  if ( e.is_app() && e.num_args() == 2) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < 2; ++i ) {
     ee[ 1 - i ] = swap_tree( e.arg(i) );
    }   
    for ( int i = 0; i < 2; ++i ) {
      cout <<" ee[" << i << "] : " << to_expr( z3_cont, ee[ i ] ) << endl;
    }
    return to_expr( z3_cont, Z3_update_term( z3_cont, e, 2, ee ) );
  }
  else 
    return e;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is "referencing counting". A Z3 object can be garbage collected by the system if its reference counter is 0. The Z3 C++ API provides "smart pointers" (`expr`, `sort`, ...) for automatically managing the reference counters for us. Your code uses `Z3_ast ee[2]`. In the for-loop, you store the result of `swap_tree(e.arg(0))` into `ee[0]`. Since the reference counter is not incremented, this Z3 object may be deleted when executing the second iteration of the loop.

Here is a possible fix:

```cpp
expr swap_tree( expr e ) {
  if ( e.is_app() && e.num_args() == 2) {
    // using smart-pointers to store the intermediate results.
    expr ee0(z3_cont), ee1(z3_cont);
    ee0 = swap_tree( e.arg(0) );
    ee1 = swap_tree( e.arg(1) );
    Z3_ast ee[2] = { ee1, ee0 };
    return to_expr( z3_cont, Z3_update_term( z3_cont, e, 2, ee ) );
  }
  else {
    return e;
  }
}
```